# Plotting the embedding diagram for a wormhole

Tags: plotting, graphics3d, physics

I want to plot an embedding diagram for the metric

```
ds2 = Exp[2/r] d[r]^2 - Exp[-2/r] d[t]^2 + 
  Exp[2/r] r^2 d[θ]^2 + 
  Exp[2/r] r^2 (Sin[θ])^2 d[φ]^2
```

How can I plot it in Mathematica?

Comment: You want to plot a 4-dimensional spacetime?

Comment: yes, please help me with it